# EWS recurrence meeting, can I use a recurrence rule (RRULE)?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, rrule

I'm trying out the EWS managed API for creating a recurring meeting.

Is it possible to define the recurrence pattern through a Recurrence Rule ([RRULE](https://nylas.com/blog/rrules/))?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use the Recurrence classes that go along with the API.  They are actually fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can Import the Ical https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672319(v=exchg.150).aspx which should allow you to do it. However not all Ical implementation are equal so depending on how its been generated results could vary so its safer just to use Recurrence Class from the API and translate between the two if you coming from Ical.